# Why session-timeout doesn't work in JBoss

Tags: java, primefaces, jboss, jboss7.x, session-timeout

i use JBoss 7.0 EAP and PrimeFaces 6.1

In my web.xml i used

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

And

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

But JBoss with both configurations close my sessions in 40 seconds all the time.

In file standalone.xml from JBoss the session timeout is configured default with 30 minutes, i try change it but my sessions is the same, 40 seconds

In other servers, even JBoss 7.0 EAP installed in my computer my sessions is work fine, but in my server productive the problem persist

Comment: Do you have a session controlled from the web server layer as well ?

Comment: Do you still have a problem with a very small webapp without jsf and primefaces?

Comment: Is there a firewall or load balancer in the mix?  That seems like a likely possibility if it works fine locally but not remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i left this job a long time ago, but this error is because a balancer intermediate into users and appserver, all the configuration on JBoss has never taken effect because balancer, just configurate balancer and fix this. Thanks all